# Power grid distribution and recipient bias

Tags: graph-theory

First of all, sorry for the vague nature of this question. I have a strong feeling that this problem I'm trying to solve has already been done by someone much smarter than me at one point and I'm more looking at where I can research a topic further rather than asking for an outright solution.

Essentially, I'm looking for a method on how to evenly distribute resources between providers and recipients, not entirely unlike a power grid in real life.

[A example provider/recipient graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU6rf.png)

In this example, all the recipients require 100 units of a resource and each provider has 350 units to be handed out. The ideal outcome would be for all recipients except D to receive 100 units from providers 1 and 2, with D receiving an equal 50 units from both provider 1 and 2.

Hopefully I've managed to communicate my problem reasonably well, again I'm mainly hoping for someone to point me in the right direction so I can research the topic further. Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should consider if https://or.stackexchange.com/  is a better home for your question!